# Javascript Disabled NoScript Tag Within Master Page Content Pages

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

My Issue is I can't redirect to page which is in the root of the solution if my javascript is disabled.

Test.aspx is a content page and its using MasterPage

Now I have written below Code to detect Javascript disabled or not.

```
<noscript>
   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=Javascript_Disabled.aspx" />
</noscript>
```

When I open my Test.aspx and if my javascript is disabled this its tries to find in my Test Folder but javascript_Disabled.aspx but actually its in my root folder.

but I am getting this URL : `http://mytestweb/Client/Test/Test/Javascript_Disabled.aspx`

How can i pass dynamic url to the noscript tag

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the redirection code.

Comment: added... Sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are missing the "/" in your url.
Try this it should work

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=/Javascript_Disabled.aspx" />
```

Your current URL resolves into an relative url which results in

```
http://mytestweb/Client/Test/Test/Javascript_Disabled.aspx
```

Adding "/" will make it refer to the root directory of your website / project resulting into an absolute url resulting into the desired url.